# How to connect mongodb from another windows server

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0, mongodb-compass

How to connect mongodb from another windows server. I have a windows server with public IP. I have installed monngoDB on that server.

I have created database and as well as user on mongodb.

Now I am trying to connect **mongodb** using **compass** from my local system but its not working.

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

try using the host PCs Ip address with the port which mongodb is running

if host PCs ip on the network is 168.194.23.43 and mongo is running on port 27017 ,
other clients should connect to your Db 168.194.23.43:27017